# How to combine two play webapps based on activator templates?

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

Let's say I have two activator templates with Play Framework. The difference between them is that one uses AngularJS while the other Reactive Mongo. They share the platform - Play Framework, but offer two additional features I'd like to have in my web application.

Is there a way to combine these two web applications that are based on the activator templates (other than looking at their source code and do the merge myself)?

Answer (score 0):

Merging them is most efficient solution IMHO in this case, as template apps are (usually) quite easy, there should not be big effort.

Other approach can be using these apps as a modules used by *third - spinning* application, anyway you will also need to extract some parts from modules and move to main app.

Finally you can use some proxy server on top of these two apps, so for client will recognize it as a single web-application, anyway probably everyone will agree that's the least efficient solution :)